# php radio buttons submission MD array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm having trouble getting the submit button to work. I'm very new to php, just a few weeks in. For now, the goal is just to have the form submit to the same page so that the user can see what he/she clicked on. I'm using a multidimensional array and a foreach loop to display the questions and choices. Just can't get any kind of submit to work. Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="">

    <?php 
        foreach($q_and_ans as $i => $q_and_an):?>

            <p><?php echo $q_and_an['question'];?></p>
            <?php foreach($q_and_an['ans'] as $a  => $ans): ?>
            <input type="radio" value="<?=$a?>" name="question[<?=$i?>]" >
            <?php echo $ans;?><br>
            <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 <?php   
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if (isset($_POST['question[0]'])){
$yourchoice0 = $POST['question[0]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice0);
}
else{ 
    echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[1]'])){
$yourchoice1 = $POST['question[1]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice1);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[2]'])){
$yourchoice2 = $POST['question[2]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice2);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[3]'])){
$yourchoice3 = $POST['question[3]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice3);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[4]'])){
$yourchoice4 = $POST['question[4]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice4);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[5]'])){
$yourchoice5 = $POST['question[5]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice5);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[6]'])){
$yourchoice6 = $POST['question[6]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice6);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[7]'])){
$yourchoice7 = $POST['question[7]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice7);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[8]'])){
$yourchoice8 = $POST['question[8]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice8);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST['question[9]'])){
$yourchoice9 = $POST['question[9]'];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice9);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
}
}
     ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Incomplete code. Where have you defined array `$q_and_ans`. Post that code too.

Comment: $q_and_ans = array(
 array('question' => 'What\'s the narrators name?',
  'ans' => array(
   'Greg Schmitz',
   'Greg Sanders',
   'Greg Smith'),
   'correct_ans' => 0),
 array('question' => 'What is Greg\'s new friend\'s name?',
  'ans' => array(
   'Jose',
   'Manuel',
   'Manuelo'),
   'correct_ans' => 1),
 array('question' => 'What beer are they drinking?',
  'ans' => array(
   'Pacifico',
   'Corona',
   'Pilsener'),
   'correct_ans' => 2),
etc. This goes on for another eight questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a better solution for your problem:

```
<?php
// Sample Data, Replace with Yours
$mcq = array(
    array('q' => 'question1?', 'opts' => ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4'], 'ans' => 0),
    array('q' => 'question2?', 'opts' => ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4'], 'ans' => 1),
    array('q' => 'question3?', 'opts' => ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4'], 'ans' => 2),
    array('q' => 'question4?', 'opts' => ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4'], 'ans' => 3));
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php
    $q_count = 0;
    foreach($mcq as $q) {
        $opt_count = 0;
    ?>
        <p>
        <?php echo 'Q.'.($q_count + 1).' '.$q['q'].'<br />'; 
        foreach($q['opts'] as $opt) {
        ?>
            <input type="radio" id="<?php echo 'opt-'.$opt_count; ?>" value="<?php echo $opt; ?>"
                name="<?php echo 'q-'.$q_count; ?>">
            <label for="<?php echo 'opt-'.$opt_count; ?>"><?php echo $opt; ?></label><br />
    <?php
            $opt_count++;
        }
        unset($opt);
        $q_count++;
    }
    unset($q);
    ?>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo '<p>Your answers are:<br />';
    $count = 0;
    foreach($mcq as $q) {
        echo 'Q.'.($count + 1).':: Your answer: ';
        if(isset($_POST['q-'.$count]))
            echo $_POST['q-'.$count];
        else
            echo 'Not Selected';
        echo ', Correct Answer: '.$q['opts'][$q['ans']].'<br />';
        $count++;
    }
    unset($q);
    echo '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you rmalviya! This is so much cleaner and easier to work with. You ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code as below:

```
if (isset($_POST["question"][0])){  //<------------ change here
$yourchoice0 = $_POST["question"][0];//<------------ change here
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice0);
}
else{ 
    echo ("select an option");
}

if (isset($_POST["question"][1])){
$yourchoice1 = $_POST['question'][1];
echo ("You selected ".$yourchoice1);
}
else{ 
echo ("select an option");
} .....
```

Comment: Thank You!!!
Now I can try to figure out the rest of this darn quiz site.